# Change DATE FORMAT from 30.9.2014 to 2014-09-30 or reverse

Tags: sqlite, date

I want to join two tables in SQLiteStudio on column **date**, but I have different date format in each table. I have tried with

```
strftime('%Y-%m-%d', date)
```

but that obviously returned wrong date. For example, from 30.9.2014 I want to get 2014-09-30 and not 2014-9-30. My table is big around 5GB in csv file. Someone know how to do this?

Comment: Why they have different format....are they filled(the tables) using the same csv?...also, can you shou us the way your are using to populate both tables, and also a one rwo sample on the csv input?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote code for this if someone needs it.

```
update table
set prc_dtm = case
    when substr(prc_dtm,3,1)= '.' and length(prc_dtm)=9
    then substr(prc_dtm,-4)||'-0'||substr(prc_dtm,4,1)||'-'||substr(prc_dtm,1,2)
    when substr(prc_dtm,2,1)= '.' and length(prc_dtm)=9
    then substr(prc_dtm,-4)||'-'||substr(prc_dtm,3,2)||'-0'||substr(prc_dtm,1,1)
    when substr(prc_dtm,2,1)= '.' and length(prc_dtm)=8
    then substr(prc_dtm,-4)||'-0'||substr(prc_dtm,3,1)||'-0'||substr(prc_dtm,1,1)
    when substr(prc_dtm,3,1)= '.' and length(prc_dtm)=10
    then substr(prc_dtm,-4)||'-'||substr(prc_dtm,4,2)||'-'||substr(prc_dtm,1,2)
    end;`
```

Answer (score 0):

The ISO format has fixed field lengths, so it is easier to convert it into the other format:

```
CAST(substr(date, 9, 2) AS num) || '.' ||
CAST(substr(date, 6, 2) AS num) || '.' ||
CAST(substr(date, 1, 4) AS num)
```